# How to enable emojis in React Native Keyboard

Tags: react-native, android-softkeyboard

I need to enable emojis in my application using react native. Is there a way to do it without using external packages.

Environment
Application Target Platform: Android

I need something like this(with the emoji option): 
[image]

this is what I get

[image]

Comment: Could you specify what your problem is? What have you tried? Emoji keyboard on eg iOS is controlled by the OS and available for choice by user on regular text fields. Do you mean you want to show only emoji?

Comment: What about android?

Comment: it's the same, the user chooses the keyboard. What have you tried? Have you not tested this?

Comment: yes. Updated the question